# Unable to generate JavaScript file after saving TypeScript file

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I am using visual studio 2012 & I have installed TypeScript For visual studio version 0.9.0.1. I have also installed web essential 2012. After I make changes in TypeScript file and save the file, same changes are not getting reflected in javascript file. Following are TypeScript setting. Please let me know the reason for this & the steps to resolve it.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Could you show the contents of the affected TypeScript file?

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I cannot share the content but I am not to resolve the issue by installing older version of type script.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by uninstalling type script library version 0.9.0.1 and installed 0.8.1.0 version and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would un-install WebEssentials + 0.8.1 and then only install 0.9.0.1 <- already supports compile on save in visual studio.

Then reinstall WebEssentials if I need it.